# Google Maps not working offline even though I already have maps downloaded

Tags: google-maps, offline, offline-map

My phone is a Nexus 4, running Android 5.1.1. I am getting this error when I try to go to a postcode in London.

[image]

> No network connection
>
> Can't connect to the network. Check your data connection and try again.
>
> <kbd>Cancel</kbd> <kbd>Try again</kbd>

But I have downloaded offline maps of London and surrounding areas.

e.g. if I go to "My Places", I can see 3 offline maps, including London*

> [image]

@Czar points out that the map files seem rather small...Maybe that is the cause, though I have an issue there too.  It doesn't give me a box to draw around what I want to download, it gives me a screen where I zoom out to how much I want, but if I zoom out too far it says it's too big.  It is only letting me save areas that are quite small like around < 30MB.

[image]

*Note- in this question, I stated that I clicked 'My Places' to see offline maps that was the case in the version I had, where I had the issue. The current Google Maps has offline maps in the menu. Google Maps can be updated from the Google Play Store.

Comment: Could it be that Maps needs a network connection for the *search* and *route calculation*? Several offline maps I know work that way. Once the route is calculated one can go offline again – the route is remembered (and unless there's some obstacle on the way and one needs to re-route, one can stay offline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure your Google Maps is up to date.

After that, double-check and make sure your "bounding box" is large enough to encompass the desired offline area.

Here's an image for reference:
[image: Screenshot with bounded area of map]

My first clue was the fact that your downloaded offline maps data size seemed rather small. For reference, my average size US city offline map on my Pixel 1 device clocks in at around 300MB.

The larger the area needed for offline use, the larger the data downloaded to your device. I believe the cap in terms of a single offline map chunk is around 1.5GB.

---

**Note added by barlop:**

> The Google Maps version I had which seemed to be an earlier version, was limiting the size of the map I could download, and with that earlier Google Maps version, I wasn't getting a box either, just an area to zoom in and out of. The solution for me was to update it which can be done from Google Play Store and taping update. Then I could draw a box to a preferred size and offline maps worked.